# I forgot security questions and rescue email

Tags: apple-id, data-recovery

Recently I got some money in my Apple ID and a few years ago I made a rescue email ( which I forgot how to enter ) and put some security questions I forgot how to awnser and I cannot buy apps ,music or movies because I need to fill in the security questions !
If I don't find an awnser on here, I will call Apple customers support.

Comment: I was just going to tell you to call Apple Support because I had the same issue this morning and they can reset the security questions for you, they'll be asking you questions like the last 4 digits of your Credit Card associated with your account.

Answer (score 1):

Call Apple support, there is no way to do this yourself.